# How to Call Activity using ListView Array

Tags: java, android

Iam using Sherlock fragment to make a Action Bar. and I have ListView in action bar, but I will my listview can call activity .. Please help me Thanks.. :)

in this code have a listview using array list . and i want to mylist can call same activity.

So it can Like menu in action bar. and when we clik listview ..he can call activity 
thank.. please help me !

```
package iqbal.apps.visitkuningan;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;

import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockListFragment;

public class AppleFragment extends SherlockListFragment{

    /** An array of items to display*/
    String apple_versions[] = new String[]{
            "Mountain Lion",
            "Lion",
            "Snow Leopard",
            "Leopard",
            "Tiger",
            "Panther"
    };

    /** An array of images to display*/
    int apple_images[] = new int[]{
            R.drawable.mountainlion,
            R.drawable.lion,
            R.drawable.snowleopard,
            R.drawable.leopard,
            R.drawable.tiger,
            R.drawable.panther
    };

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){

        // Each row in the list stores country name, currency and flag
        List<HashMap<String,String>> aList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();

        for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
                HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<String,String>();
            hm.put("txt", apple_versions[i]);
            hm.put("img", Integer.toString(apple_images[i]  ) );
            aList.add(hm);
        }

        // Keys used in Hashmap
        String[] from = { "img","txt" };

        // Ids of views in listview_layout
        int[] to = { R.id.img,R.id.txt};

        // Instantiating an adapter to store each items
        // R.layout.listview_layout defines the layout of each item
        SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity().getBaseContext(), aList, R.layout.listview_layout, from, to);


        // Setting the adapter to the listView
        setListAdapter(adapter);

        return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use setOnItemClickListener() on your listview

```
  listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0,View arg1, int position, long arg3) {
    Intent n = null; 
    switch (position){
       case 0: 
         n = new Intent(getActivity(), Class0.class);
         break;
       case 1: 
         n = new Intent(getActivity(), Class1.class);
         break;
    }
    if(null!=n)
      startActivity(n);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

List navigation in the ActionBar does not require a ListFragment (or a SherlockListFragment in your case). Your code is setting the adapter for the ListView that is the *content* of the Activity. What you want is to set the ActionBar's navigation mode and provide the adapter to the ActionBar. In your onCreate:

```
ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST);
actionBar.setListNavigationCallbacks(adapter, navigationListener);
```

`adapter` is a `SpinnerAdapter` implementation. navigationListener is a `ActionBar.OnNavigationListener` implementation. When the user presses an item from the dropdown list in the ActionBar, your navigationListener's `onNavigationItemSelected` method gets called and it passes in the position and the id of the selected item. In that callback you can implement starting another activity.

See [ActionBar](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.html) and [ActionBar.OnNavigationListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.OnNavigationListener.html) -- ActionBarSherlock mirrors the standard Android ActionBar APIs.